# Mac Voiceover repeats selectWoo dropdown twice

Tags: javascript, css, accessibility, jquery-select2

The selectWoo library is supposed to be a more accessible version of select2, which is a JS/CSS library that allows you to style dropdowns.  However, I'm finding that Mac Voiceover repeats dropdown information twice.  Per the below example (just the dropdown, for simplicity):

```
<html>
     <head>
          <link href="selectWoo.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
          <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
          <script type="text/javascript" src="selectWoo.min.js"></script>
     </head>
     <body>
          <form id="test-form" method="post" action="" name="accessible">
               <select id="select-something" class="form-control">
                    <option value="blah" selected="" disabled="" hidden="">Select Something</option>
               </select>
          </form>
          <script type="text/javascript">
               $("#select-something").selectWoo();
          </script>
     </body>
</html>
```

When tabbing over to the dropdown box, Mac Voiceover reads this as: "Select Something, Select something, menu pop up, menu pop-up combo box".  This doesn't seem ideal, and I'm wondering why it reads the default value twice.

This is the code that SelectWoo winds up generating in the browser:

```
<html>
     <head>
          <link href="selectWoo.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
          <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
          <script type="text/javascript" src="selectWoo.min.js"></script>
     </head>
     <body>
          <form id="test-form" method="post" action="" name="accessible">
               <select id="select-something" class="form-control select2-hidden-accessible" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true">
                    <option value="blah" selected="" disabled="" hidden="">Select Something</option>
               </select>
               <span class="select2 select2-container select2-container--default" dir="ltr" style="width: 128px;">
                    <span class="selection">
                         <span class="select2-selection select2-selection--single" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" tabindex="0" aria-labelledby="select2-select-something-container" role="combobox">
                              <span class="select2-selection__rendered" id="select2-select-something-container" role="textbox" aria-readonly="true" title="Select Something">
                                   Select Something
                              </span>
                              <span class="select2-selection__arrow" role="presentation"><b role="presentation"></b></span>
                         </span>
                    </span>
                    <span class="dropdown-wrapper" aria-hidden="true"></span>
               </span>
          </form>
          <script type="text/javascript">
               $("#select-something").selectWoo();
          </script>
     </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What does the related CSS do?

Comment: It might be due to the title being set for the textbox. Are you able to try that out, maybe by turning your code into an interactive example?